# why is ADODB inserting NULL values on update?

Tags: sql, mysql, excel, ms-access, odbc

i have:

```
With rs
    .AddNew ' create a new record
    ' add values to each field in the record
    .Fields("datapath") = dpath
    .Fields("analysistime") = "atime"
    .Fields("reporttime") = "rtime"
    .Fields("lastcalib") = "lcalib"
    .Fields("analystname") = "aname"
    .Fields("reportname") = "rname"
    .Fields("batchstate") = "bstate"
    .Fields("instrument") = "NA"
    .Update ' stores the new record
End With
```

when i check the database, it looks like it ONLY inserted the last field!

has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Is that real data? Surely reporttime is a datetime field and will not accept "rtime" text? This is just an example, the other fields suffer from similar problems.

Comment: remou, good question, nope im certain its all text, it will accept it definitely

Comment: I am afraid I have tested this with Excel and MySQL using a test table  and all fields updated as expected. Try this table for testing: create table binfo (datapath text,analysistime text,reporttime text,lastcalib text,analystname text, reportname text, batchstate text, instrument text);

Comment: remou, there is one more field there called rowid primary key int(11) - do you think that could have been the problem?

Comment: btw what you suggested me to do worked well!

Comment: I do not think so, is it an autonumber field?

Comment: I think you should check the table schema.

Comment: can you try on this table: Create Table: CREATE TABLE `batchinfo` (
  `rowid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datapath` text,
  `analysistime` text,
  `reporttime` text,
  `lastcalib` text,
  `analystname` text,
  `reportname` text,
  `batchstate` text,
  `instrument` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rowid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=67 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: Okay, that does not work. But I cannot see the solution at the moment.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, if you do see a solution please let me know!

Comment: i tried lances answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823364/update-record-only-works-when-there-is-no-auto-increment but it did not work

Comment: Apparently this is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829453/connecting-excel-to-mysql-update-problem/2829864#2829864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: The code below works, but the corret solution can be found here: [Connecting Excel to Mysql Update PROBLEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829453/connecting-excel-to-mysql-update-problem/2829864#2829864)

It involves the difficulties of using text data type.

---

This seems to work, but don't ask me why:

```
dpath = "a" ''Trim(Range("B2").Text)
atime = "a" ''Trim(Range("B3").Text)
rtime = "a" ''Trim(Range("B4").Text)
lcalib = "a" ''Trim(Range("B5").Text)
aname = "a" ''Trim(Range("B6").Text)
rname = "a" ''Trim(Range("B7").Text)
bstate = "a" ''Trim(Range("B8").Text)

cn.Open strCon
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = _
    "INSERT INTO `batchinfo` (`datapath`, `analysistime`," _
       & "`reporttime`,`lastcalib`,`analystname`,`reportname`," _
       & "`batchstate`,`instrument`) " _
       & "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"

cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("datapath", adChar, adParamInput, 100)
cmd.Parameters.Append _
     cmd.CreateParameter("analysistime", adChar, adParamInput, 100)
cmd.Parameters.Append _
     cmd.CreateParameter("reporttime", adChar, adParamInput, 100)
cmd.Parameters.Append _
     cmd.CreateParameter("lastcalib", adChar, adParamInput, 100)
cmd.Parameters.Append _
     cmd.CreateParameter("analystname", adChar, adParamInput, 100)
cmd.Parameters.Append _
     cmd.CreateParameter("reportname", adChar, adParamInput, 100)
cmd.Parameters.Append _
     cmd.CreateParameter("batchstate", adChar, adParamInput, 100)
cmd.Parameters.Append _
     cmd.CreateParameter("instrument", adChar, adParamInput, 100)

cmd.Parameters("datapath").Value = "abc"
cmd.Parameters("analysistime").Value = atime
cmd.Parameters("reporttime").Value = rtime
cmd.Parameters("lastcalib").Value = lcalib
cmd.Parameters("analystname").Value = aname
cmd.Parameters("reportname").Value = rname
cmd.Parameters("batchstate").Value = "bstate"
cmd.Parameters("instrument").Value = "NA"

cmd.Execute
```